# Another bizarre sum involving a binomial coefficient and inverse powers of integers.

Tags: summation, harmonic-numbers, beta-function, polygamma

In the attempt to answer [Binomial identity involving Harmonic numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3926458/binomial-identity-involving-harmonic-numbers/3940197#3940197) we stumbled on the following problem.
Let $i\ge 0 $ and $k \ge i+2 $ and $p \ge 1$  be integers. Consider a following sum:

\begin{equation}
{\mathfrak S}^k_{i,p} := \sum\limits_{j=2}^{k-i} \binom{k}{i+j} \frac{(-1)^j}{(j-1)^p} \quad (i)
\end{equation}

By using the usual trick $1/j^p = \int\limits_0^\infty \frac{t^{p-1}}{(p-1)!} e^{-j t} dt$ and then by summing up the resulting binomial series and finally by using the Faa di Bruno formula  we have arrived at the following:

\begin{eqnarray}
{\mathfrak S}^k_{i,p} &=& \lim\limits_{\theta \rightarrow 0} \left[
\frac{(-1)^{p-1+i}}{(p-1)!} \frac{d^{p-1}}{d \theta^{p-1}} \left[
B(k+1,\theta-i-1)
\right] - \sum\limits_{j=0}^{i+1} \binom{k}{j} (-1)^{j+i} \frac{1}{(\theta-i+j-1)^p}
\right] \\
&=& \lim\limits_{\theta \rightarrow 0} \left[(-1)^{p-1+i} B(k+1,\theta-i-1)
\sum\limits_{\sum\limits_{\xi=1}^{p-1} \xi m_\xi =p-1}
\frac{\prod\limits_{\xi=1}^{p-1} \left( \psi^{(\xi-1)}(\theta-i-1) - \psi^{(\xi-1)}(\theta-i+k)\right)^{m_\xi}}{\prod\limits_{\xi=1}^{p-1} (\xi!)^{m_\xi} m_\xi!}
- \sum\limits_{j=0}^{i+1} \binom{k}{j} (-1)^{j+i} \frac{1}{(\theta-i+j-1)^p}
\right] \quad(ii)
\end{eqnarray}
In the second line $\psi^{(j)}$ is the polygamma function .

The code below verifies the result:

```
{i} = RandomInteger[{1, 5}, 1]; p = RandomInteger[{3, 6}];
l1 = Table[
  Sum[ Binomial[k, j + i] (-1)^j/(j - 1)^p, {j, 2, k - i}], {k, i + 2,
    10}]
N[l1]
th =.;
l2 = Table[
   Normal[Series[(-1)^(p - 1 + i)/(p - 1)! D[ 
       Beta[k + 1, th - i - 1] - 
        Sum[ Binomial[k, j] (-1)^j 1/(th - i + j - 1), {j, 0, 
          i + 1}], {th, p - 1}], {th, 0, 0}]], {k, i + 2, 10}] // N
l3 = Table[
   Normal[Series[
     Beta[k + 1, th - i - 1] Total[
        DeleteCases[
         Flatten[Table[ 
           With[{mm = (p - 1 - Sum[xi m[xi], {xi, 1, p - 2}])/(p - 
                 1)}, If[
             Element[mm, 
              Integers], (-1)^(p - 1 + i)/
               Product[
                m[xi]!, {xi, 1, p - 1}] Product[((
                 PolyGamma[xi - 1, th - i - 1] - 
                  PolyGamma[xi - 1, th - i + k])/xi!)^
                m[xi], {xi, 1, p - 1}] /. m[p - 1] :> mm, {}]], 
           Evaluate[
            Sequence @@ 
             Table[{m[q], 0, 
               Floor[(p - 1 - Sum[xi m[xi], {xi, 1, q - 1}])/q]}, {q, 
               1, p - 2}]]], p - 3], {}]] - 
      Sum[ Binomial[k, j] (-1)^j (-1)^(i)/(th - i + j - 1)^p, {j, 0, 
        i + 1}], {th, 0, 0}]], {k, i + 2, 10}];
FullSimplify[l3]
```

[image]

In particular we have:
\begin{eqnarray}
{\mathfrak S}^{k}_{i,1} &=& \binom{k}{i+1} \frac{1}{1!} \left( H_{k-i-1} - H_{i+1} \right) - \sum\limits_{j=0}^i \binom{k}{j} \frac{(-1)^{j+i}}{(j-i-1)^1} \\
{\mathfrak S}^{k}_{i,2} &=& \binom{k}{i+1} \frac{1}{2!} \left( (H_{k-i-1}-H_{i+1})^2 + H_{i+1}^{(2)} + H_{k-i-1}^{(2)}  \right) - \sum\limits_{j=0}^i \binom{k}{j} \frac{(-1)^{j+i}}{(j-i-1)^2} \\
{\mathfrak S}^{k}_{i,3} &=& \binom{k}{i+1} \frac{1}{3!} \left(
(H_{k-i-1}-H_{i+1})^3 + 3 (H_{i+1}^{(2)} + H_{k-i-1}^{(2)}) \cdot (H_{k-i-1}-H_{i+1}) + 2 (H_{k-i-1}^{(3)} - H_{i+1}^{(3)})
\right)-  \sum\limits_{j=0}^i \binom{k}{j} \frac{(-1)^{j+i}}{(j-i-1)^3} 
\end{eqnarray}

```
In[127]:= Clear[H];
H[i_] := HarmonicNumber[i];
H[i_, p_] := HarmonicNumber[i, p];

l1 = Table[
   Sum[ Binomial[k, j + i] (-1)^j/(j - 1)^1, {j, 2, k - i}], {i, 0, 
    5}, {k, i + 2, 10}];
l2 = Table[
   Binomial[k, 
      i + 1] (HarmonicNumber[k - i - 1] - HarmonicNumber[i + 1]) - 
    Sum[ Binomial[k, j] (-1)^(j + i)/(j - i - 1), {j, 0, i}], {i, 0, 
    5}, {k, i + 2, 10}];
l1 - l2

l1 = Table[
   Sum[ Binomial[k, j + i] (-1)^j/(j - 1)^2, {j, 2, k - i}], {i, 0, 
    5}, {k, i + 2, 10}];
l2 = Table[
   Binomial[k, i + 1] 1/
      2 ((H[1 + i] - H[k - i - 1])^2 + H[1 + i, 2] + 
       H[-1 - i + k, 2]) - 
    Sum[ Binomial[k, j] (-1)^(j + i)/(j - i - 1)^2, {j, 0, i}], {i, 0,
     5}, {k, i + 2, 10}];
l1 - l2

l1 = Table[
   Sum[ Binomial[k, j + i] (-1)^j/(j - 1)^3, {j, 2, k - i}], {i, 0, 
    5}, {k, i + 2, 10}];
l2 = Table[
   Binomial[k, i + 1] 1/
     6 ((-H[1 + i] + H[k - i - 1])^3 + 
       3 (H[1 + i, 2] +  H[-1 - i + k, 2]) (-H[1 + i] + 
          H[-1 - i + k]) + 2 (-H[1 + i, 3] + H[-1 - i + k, 3])) - 
    Sum[ Binomial[k, j] (-1)^(j + i)/(j - i - 1)^3, {j, 0, i}], {i, 0,
     5}, {k, i + 2, 10}];
l1 - l2

Out[132]= {{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}}

Out[135]= {{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}}

Out[138]= {{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 
  0}}
```

Unfortunately the result $(ii)$ is highly singular and it is hard to carry out the limit $\theta \rightarrow 0$ in full generality. My question would therefore be how to perform this limit and obtain a closed form result for the sum in question.

Comment: I don't know if this helps. For integer $p\ge1$ the sum can be evaluated to S(i,k,p) = Binomial[k, 
  2 + i] HypergeometricPFQ[{1, 1, ..., 1, 2 + i - k}, {2, ..., 2, 3 + i}, 
  1] Here in the hypergeometric function the first argument has $p+2$ times the parameter $1$, and the second argument has $p+1$ times the parameter $2$

Comment: @Dr. Wolfgang Hintze Yes this is interesting. Actually Mathematica also expresses the result in terms of those hypergeometric functions but is not capable of simplifying the results any further. But now I think this problem isn't that hard after all because I evaluated it for $p=1,2,3$ and I can see the pattern already.

Answer (score 1):

Now let us assume that $p \ge 2$ is an arbitrary integer. We also define coefficients as below:

\begin{equation}
{\mathcal S}^{\pm}_p(i):= \frac{1}{p!} \left. \frac{d^p}{d x^p}  e^{\sum\limits_{q=1}^\infty (\mp 1)^{q-1} \frac{H^{(q)}_i}{q} x^q } \right|_{x=0}
\end{equation}

We compute the first term in the right hand side as follows:

\begin{eqnarray}
&&\frac{(-1)^{p-1+i}}{(p-1)!}  \frac{d^{p-1}}{d \theta^{p-1}} B(k+1,\theta-i-1) =\\
&&\frac{(-1)^{p-1+i}}{(p-1)!}  \frac{d^{p-1}}{d \theta^{p-1}} \left(\frac{1}{\prod\limits_{p=1}^{i+1} (\theta-p)} \cdot \frac{k!}{\theta}  \cdot \frac{1}{ \prod\limits_{p=1}^{k-i-1} (\theta+p)} \right) = \\
&&\frac{(-1)^{p}}{(p-1)!}  \binom{k}{i+1} \frac{d^{p-1}}{d \theta^{p-1}} \left(\frac{1}{\prod\limits_{p=1}^{i+1} (-\frac{\theta}{p}+1)} \cdot \frac{1}{\theta}  \cdot \frac{1}{ \prod\limits_{p=1}^{k-i-1} (\frac{\theta}{p}+1)} \right) = \\
&&\frac{(-1)^{p}}{(p-1)!}  \binom{k}{i+1} \frac{d^{p-1}}{d \theta^{p-1}} 
\left(
\frac{1}{\theta} \cdot 
\frac{1}{\left[1+ \sum\limits_{q_1=1}^\infty (-\theta)^{q_1} {\mathcal S}^{+}_{q_1}(i+1) \right]} \cdot 
\frac{1}{\left[1+ \sum\limits_{q_2=1}^\infty (+\theta)^{q_2} {\mathcal S}^{+}_{q_2}(k-i-1) \right]}
\right) = \\
&&
\frac{(-1)^{p}}{(p-1)!}  \binom{k}{i+1} \frac{d^{p-1}}{d \theta^{p-1}} 
\left(
\frac{1}{\theta} \cdot 
\sum\limits_{q_1=0}^\infty (+\theta)^{q_1} {\mathcal S}^{-}_{q_1}(i+1) \cdot 
\sum\limits_{q_2=0}^\infty (-\theta)^{q_2} {\mathcal S}^{-}_{q_2}(k-i-1)
\right) = \\
&&
\frac{(-1)^{p}}{(p-1)!}  \binom{k}{i+1} \frac{d^{p-1}}{d \theta^{p-1}} 
\left(
\frac{1}{\theta} + 
(-1)^q \sum\limits_{q=1}^\infty \theta^{q-1} 
\sum\limits_{q_1+q_2=q} (-1)^{q_1} {\mathcal S}^{-}_{q_1}(i+1) \cdot  {\mathcal S}^{-}_{q_2}(k-i-1)
\right) = \\
&&
\binom{k}{i+1} \left[
\frac{(-1)^1}{\theta^p} + 
\left(\sum\limits_{q_1+q_2=p} (-1)^{q_1} {\mathcal S}^{-}_{q_1}(i+1) \cdot  {\mathcal S}^{-}_{q_2}(k-i-1)
\right) + O\left(\theta^{p+1} \right)
\right]
\end{eqnarray}

Now we can see that the first term in the square brackets cancels the last term , i.e. the $j=i+1$ term in the last sum in $(ii)$ . The singularities cancel out nicely and now it is straightforward to take the limit . So the result reads:

\begin{eqnarray}
{\mathfrak S}^k_{i,p} &=& \binom{k}{i+1} \left[\sum\limits_{q_1=0}^p (-1)^{q_1}{\mathcal S}^{-}_{q_1}(i+1) \cdot  {\mathcal S}^{-}_{p-q_1}(k-i-1)\right]
-
\sum\limits_{j=0}^i \binom{k}{j} \frac{(-1)^{j+i}}{(j-i-1)^p} \\
&=& \binom{k}{i+1} \cdot \left(
\sum\limits_{\sum\limits_{j=1}^p j \cdot m_j = p} 
\frac{1}{\prod\limits_{j=1}^p m_j!} \prod\limits_{j=1}^p \left[ \frac{(-1)^j H^{(j)}_{i+1} + H^{(j)}_{k-i-1}}{j} \right]^{m_j}
\right)
-
\sum\limits_{j=0}^i \binom{k}{j} \frac{(-1)^{j+i}}{(j-i-1)^p}
\end{eqnarray}

```
In[772]:= p = RandomInteger[{2, 15}]; Clear[H]; k =.; i =.; M = 10;
l1 = Table[
   Sum[ Binomial[k, j + i] (-1)^j/(j - 1)^p, {j, 2, k - i}], {i, 0, 
    M}, {k, i + 2, 2 M}];
ff[k_, i_] = 
  Binomial[k, 
     i + 1] (Sum[ (-1)^p1/p1! 1/(p - p1)! D[
         Exp[ Sum[ H[i + 1, q]/q x^q, {q, 1, M}]], {x, p1}] D[
         Exp[ Sum[ H[k - i - 1, q]/q x^q, {q, 1, M}]], {x, 
          p - p1}], {p1, 0, p}] /. x :> 0) - 
   Sum[ Binomial[k, j] (-1)^(j + i)/(j - i - 1)^p, {j, 0, i}];
H[i_] := HarmonicNumber[i];
H[i_, p_] := HarmonicNumber[i, p];
l2 = Table[ff[k, i], {i, 0, M}, {k, i + 2, 2 M}];
l1 - l2

Out[778]= {{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}}
```

Update: Here we also partially evaluate the remaining sum.
Take $i \ge 0 $ and $\xi =0,\cdots, i$ be integers then let us firstly define some coefficients:

\begin{eqnarray}
{\mathcal A}^{(\xi)}_{i,p} &:=& \sum\limits_{j=0}^\xi \binom{i+1}{\xi-j}  \frac{1}{(\xi-j-i-1)^{p-1}} \binom{-i+\xi-1}{j} \\
&=& \left\{
\begin{array}{rrr}
1 & \quad \mbox{if $p=1$}\\
H_{i-\xi}- H_{i+1} & \quad \mbox{if $p=2$} \\
\frac{1}{2} \left( (H_{i+1}^{(2)} - H_{i-\xi}^{(2)}) + (H_{i+1} - H_{i-\xi})^2 \right) & \quad \mbox{if $p=3$} \\
\vdots
\end{array}
\right.
\end{eqnarray}

now our remaining sum reads:

\begin{eqnarray}
\sum\limits_{j=0}^i \binom{k}{j} \frac{(-1)^{j+i}}{(j-i-1)^p} &=&
-\binom{k}{i+1} \cdot \sum\limits_{\xi=0}^i \frac{1}{(k-\xi)}  \cdot {\mathcal A}^{(\xi)}_{i,p} \quad (i)
\end{eqnarray}

```
In[858]:= p = RandomInteger[{1, 5}]; k =.; 
H[i_, p_] := HarmonicNumber[i, p]; M = 10;
AA[xi_, i_, p_] := 
  Which[p == 1, 1, p == 2, 
   HarmonicNumber[i - xi] - HarmonicNumber[1 + i], p == 3, 
   1/2 (H[1 + i, 2] - 
      H[i - xi, 
       2] + (HarmonicNumber[1 + i] - HarmonicNumber[i - xi])^2), True,
    Sum[ Binomial[i + 1, 
      xi - j] 1/(xi - j - i - 1)^(p - 1) Binomial[-i + xi - 1, j], {j,
      0, xi}]];
l1 = Table[
   Sum[Binomial[k, j] (-1)^(j + i)/(j - i - 1)^p, {j, 0, i}], {p, 1, 
    5}, {i, 0, M}];
l2 = Table[-Binomial[k, i + 1] Sum[ 
     1/(k - xi) AA[xi, i, p] , {xi, 0, i}], {p, 1, 5}, {i, 0, M}];
FullSimplify[l1 - l2]

Out[862]= {{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}}
```

Equation $(i)$ comes from factoring out the the binomial factor  and then decomposing the rest into partial fractions in the variable $k$ and then all the similar terms together and simplifying.

Comment: I wonder if your final result is really a simplification with respect to the original sum (i).

Comment: @Dr. Wolfgang Hintze Of course it is a simplification.For big values of $k$ the original sum requires $O(k)$ operations whereas in case of the final result the computational expense is independent of $k$ and only depends on $p$ and $i$. Besides by looking at the original sum there is no way to assess the large-$k$ behavior and here we do see this behavior.

Comment: @ Przemo As to the asymptotics in $k$, you can get rid of $k$ in the upper summation index by replacing $k-i$ by $\infty$ which leaves $k$ only in the binomial coefficient.

Comment: @ Dr. Wolfgang Hintze The final result gives us much more than only the binomial coefficient. It tells us for example that there is a logarithmic correction, something that is not seen at all from the original sum. In a way those derivations are pretty much similar to the evaluations of Euler sums, something that is very popular in this site. Again, i am not quite sure what are you on about asking your question ?

Comment: @ Przemo, I appreciate your answered to my question. Thank you.